# Implementing a match counter into a lotto number guesser

Tags: python, counter

im rather new to python and found someones lottery simulation in github. After playing around with it for a while i wanted to add a counter, that counts the number of matches of your Number out of the total draws.

I don't know if it is because i did not write the code myself, but i can't seem to make it happen. I've tried some of pythons counter modules bu that did'nt seem to be the right thing.

Heres my code:

```
import random
import time

### TODO - Refactor GetDrawNumbers (add timers)
### TODO - Refactor CheckNumbers

def GetDrawNumbers():
    drawNumbers = []
    for i in range(6):
        x = None
        while (x == None or x in drawNumbers):
            x = random.randint(1, 49)
        drawNumbers.append(x)
    return drawNumbers

def CheckNumbers(myTicket, actualNumbers):
    numbersMatched = 0
    for number in myTicket:
        if number in actualNumbers:
            numbersMatched += 1
    return numbersMatched

### Script starts here

startTime = time.perf_counter()

myNumbers = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]

for draw in range(2000):
    drawNumber = draw + 1
    thisWeeksDraw = GetDrawNumbers()
    numbersMatched = CheckNumbers(myNumbers, thisWeeksDraw)
    ##print("Week " + str(drawNumber) + " numbers : " + str(thisWeeksDraw) + " (" + str(numbersMatched) + " matched)")
    if numbersMatched == 4:
        print("Week " + str(drawNumber) + " numbers : " + str(thisWeeksDraw) + " (" + str(numbersMatched) + " matched)")

count = numbersMatched
print("Total matches: " + str(count))

endTime = time.perf_counter()
elapsedTime = endTime - startTime

print("Completed in " + str(elapsedTime) + " seconds!")
```

If anyone knows a way to implement a counter, that counts the number of times this the program gets 3,4,5 or 6 correct matches i would be super relieved! It's not that this project would be super important but solving the problem would be a milestone for me and my learning process!

Thanks in advance and best wishes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this where I have added a check of the numbersMatched value and increment a counter whenever it is 3 or more

```
import random
import time

### TODO - Refactor GetDrawNumbers (add timers)
### TODO - Refactor CheckNumbers

def GetDrawNumbers():
    drawNumbers = []
    for i in range(6):
        x = None
        while (x == None or x in drawNumbers):
            x = random.randint(1, 49)
        drawNumbers.append(x)
    return drawNumbers

def CheckNumbers(myTicket, actualNumbers):
    numbersMatched = 0
    for number in myTicket:
        if number in actualNumbers:
            numbersMatched += 1
    return numbersMatched

### Script starts here

startTime = time.perf_counter()

myNumbers = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]

countOfThreeOrMoreMatched = 0
for draw in range(2000):
    drawNumber = draw + 1
    thisWeeksDraw = GetDrawNumbers()
    numbersMatched = CheckNumbers(myNumbers, thisWeeksDraw)
    ##print("Week " + str(drawNumber) + " numbers : " + str(thisWeeksDraw) + " (" + str(numbersMatched) + " matched)")
    if numbersMatched >= 3:
        countOfThreeOrMoreMatched += 1
    if numbersMatched == 4:
        print("Week " + str(drawNumber) + " numbers : " + str(thisWeeksDraw) + " (" + str(numbersMatched) + " matched)")

print(f"Count with 3 or more matches {countOfThreeOrMoreMatched}")
count = numbersMatched
print("Total matches: " + str(count))

endTime = time.perf_counter()
elapsedTime = endTime - startTime

print("Completed in " + str(elapsedTime) + " seconds!")
```